# Using FlatMap in RxJava 2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava 2 on a new project (I've been using RxJava 1 for a long time) and I have some problems with using a flatMap (or maybe flatMapSingle?).
There seems to be something I'm missing in the whole concept.

mObjectManager.getAllObjects returns a `AsyncProcessor<List<Object>>`.
(I replaced the actual Class name with 'Object').

```
Disposable subscription = mObjectManager.getAllObjects()
                .flatMapSingle(new Function<List<Object>, SingleSource<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public SingleSource<Object > apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List<Object> objects) throws Exception {
                        // TODO WHAT GOES HERE?!
                    }
                }).filter(new Predicate<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Object object) throws Exception {
                        return TextUtils.isEmpty(mSearchTerm) || object.name.toLowerCase().contains(mSearchTerm.toLowerCase());
                    }
                }).toSortedList(new Comparator<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Object c1, Object c2) {
                        return c1.name.compareTo(c2.name);
                    }
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List<Object> objects) throws Exception {
                        processObjects(objects);
                    }
                });
```

I'm wondering how I can transform the list to a SingleSource?
How is the flatMap being used in RxJava 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer after all.
`Flowable.fromIterable` does the trick!

```
...
.flatMap(new Function<List<Object>, Publisher< Object >>() {
    @Override
    public Publisher< Object > apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List< Object > objects) throws Exception {
        return Flowable.fromIterable(objects);
   }
})
```

Comment: Think about Android WorkManager, that is very easy to use, less verbose. Supports chaining for request.